# Organizing "elmah.sqlservercompact" nuget package

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-ce, elmah, elmah.mvc

I installed both the `elmah.mvc` and `elmah.sqlservercompact` ([package link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah.sqlservercompact)) nuget packages. This gets elmah to log to Sql Server Compact.

Problem is it copies a large number of files from the `_bin_deployableAssemblies` folder, on every build.

How do I change this to deploy/copy *only* if file has changed, like I can do for other resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems when I install the `SqlServerCe` package manually, it doesn't add all those binaries to the build file.